# Changing value in one component affects another

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have an angular 6 application, which has a top bar and a content area below this. These are different component and I am currently developing the user profile page. Name of the user is also displayed in the top bar.

My problem is like whenever I have updated the user's name in EditUser page, it successfully saves, but the same is not updated on the top bar. In Vue.js, I can simply handle this with a Vuex store; but how can I handle this in Angular 6.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Bro, don't just post the text without any code. It will get downvotes and everyone is not nice like these 2 gentlemen who posted answers and did not downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Next time post a bit of code. Since there isn't, I'll show you how to do it with an example.

Let's assume we have two component, A and B. And the changes will be reflected on both of two components.

Service :

```
export class YourService{
  private data$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  data = this.data$.asObservable();

  public setData(data: string){
    this.data$.next(data);
  }
}
```

Component A/B.html :

```
<div>{{something}}</div>
```

Component A/B.ts :

```
isAlive = true;
something: string;

constructor(
  private service: YourService
) { }

ngOnInit(){
  this.service.data
  .takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
  .subscribe( res => {
    if(!!res){
      this.something = res;
    }
  });
}

    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.isAlive = false;
    }
```

Component that change the status:

```
export class AnotherComponent{
  constructor(
    private service: YourService
  ) { }

  private changeData(data: string){
    this.service.setData(data);
  }
}
```

Now everything is working fine. `BehaviorSubject` allow the communication between components. whenever the function `changeData` is fired, you will see the changes on both of your components.

`takeWhile` is for unsubscribing when the component die.

If you have more question, feel free to ask them to me and I will edit this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create service to exchange data between components. It could be UserService that provide access to current user information.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    user: UserInfo;
    // define user here (load from backend or somehow else)
}
```

In **user-profile.component.ts**

```
export class UserProfileComponent {

constructor(public userService: UserService) { }
}
```

**user-profile.component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="userService.user.name">
```

In **header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent {

constructor(public userService: UserService) { }
}
```

**header.component.html**

```
<span>{{ userService.user.name }}</span>
```

So the anggular DI will create a singleton `UserService` and injects the same object to both components. And when you change it in any of them the changes will be shown in other.