# Passing data from Parent Component to Child Component

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I want to pass data from Parent Component to Child Component.
One way to achieve this is by using `@input()` Decorator. Today I came across another method. That is, getting the local reference of Child Component using `@ViewChild` and assigning the property to its instance. Is this a correct way to pass data?

Comment: Take a look at this please :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51384602/767625

Comment: You can do it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52382447/changing-value-in-one-component-affects-another/52382688#52382688

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Thank you Sir. Yes that is one more way. But please let me know if below code is correct way or not ? It works fine though.

 @ViewChild('employeeComponent') employee : employeeComponent;
this.employee.newProperty = {};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if you don't absolutely need it, you should prefer using the `@Input()` decorator and pass values to the child component using it.

`@ViewChild` reference is often used in cases when you need to call some component's methods and not just update the property value. It gives you more flexibility.

Also, in terms of change detection, using `@Input` is more efficient. Especially if you use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. This way Angular knows that the only time it needs to detect changes is when the `@Input` changes.

Putting change detection aside, it's simply not a common practice to update the properties using `ViewChild()` and such code can be less comprehensible and robust.

In cases when you simply need to pass the value from the parent to child component you should definitely use `@Input`.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are valid. However, using `@Input` makes it more clear it's an input. This might not something you need, but could be very usefull to other developers.

Using `@ViewChild` you get a reference to the component. Of course you can set a property, but why would you if you have an `@Input`.  But you could call a method using the `@ViewChild`.

Though it is perfectly valid to use it, I try to avoid it as much as possibler because it's not always very intuitive.